# setTimeout conflict in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am new here and new to JV/web-dev and trying to create a light-weight reaction game in JS and running into a few issues:

1. I am trying to initialize the game once a button is clicked, but I am finding that upon page refresh the game starts on it's own? I call the button fxn "time_init()" at the bottom of the script but it still loads on its own?
2. How do I go about making the game only go for a set time like 15seconds? It continues on...? I feel the setTimeout method is lacking or i'm using it wrong?
3. Lastly, if I want to count the number of times a square is clicked versus a circle and output their reaction time after that, what is the best way to do it? I'm thinking just creating a while-loop that just counts the number of times a square is clicked while the game is being played..

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="time_init()" />

<p class="bold">Your time: <span id="time">0</span>s</p>

<div id="box"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var clickedTime; var createdTime; var reactionTime;

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color +=letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

function time_init() {
setTimeout('makeBox()', 1000);}


function makeBox() {

    var time=Math.random();

    time=time*1500;

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (Math.random()>0.5) {
            document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius="100px";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius="";
        }

        var top=Math.random();
        top=top*500;
        var left=Math.random();
        left=left*800;

        document.getElementById("box").style.top=top+"px";

        document.getElementById("box").style.left=left+"px";

        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor=getRandomColor();

        document.getElementById("box").style.display="block";

        createdTime=Date.now();

    }, time);

}

document.getElementById("box").onclick=function() {

    clickedTime=Date.now();

    reactionTime= (clickedTime - createdTime)/1000;

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=reactionTime;

    this.style.display="none";

    makeBox();

}

time_init();
```

Comment: setTimeout expects a function as first paramter, you're passing a string. Remove the quotes around makeBox()

Comment: If you're not having trouble with css, remove the tag from the question!

Comment: @lascort if he just removes the quotes it'll execute `makebox()` immediately. recommended practice is `setTimeout(makeBox, 1000)` but as is the quoted code will get eval'd and run when expected.

Comment: at the end of your code you call `time_init();` , what will run the function without a click

Comment: @lascort: You *can* pass a string like that to `setTimeout`.  It's a horrible practice, but it's valid.  It will cause the system to use `eval` on it, though, that's why it's not suggested.

Comment: @lincolnk you're right, I was too concerned with the quotes and let that one slip, good call

Comment: @lascort - `setTimeout` expects both a function and a string for the first parameter. There is no syntactical and other error thrown for passing a string, though passing a function is usually recommended.

Comment: ok point taken haha, never ever used setTimeout that way, can't imagine why anyone would neither, but if it works... my bad!

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly calling `time_init();` at the end of your code. That will kick things off immediately, and call `makebox()` after 1 second.

If you want to shut things down after 15 seconds, create a flag variable and another timeout to flip it after that time. Then you check that flag variable whenever you do anything to decide if you keep doing it or not.

```
var isRunning = true;
setTimeout( function() { isRunning=false; }, 15000 );

document.getElementById("box").onclick=function() {

    clickedTime=Date.now();

    reactionTime= (clickedTime - createdTime)/1000;

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=reactionTime;

    this.style.display="none";

    if ( isRunning ) {
        makeBox();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks lincoln this worked!

Awesome, thank you guys very much!

I have taken the quotes out and deleted the callto time_init at the end and its working now.

Any idea how to only let it run for 15s after start is clicked? Is that another function I need to create or can I end it in the setTimout fxn in time_init?

Comment: To expound on this, I am making two elements "box" and "circle" -- is it possible to pass the "document.getElementById("box").onclick=function() both the box and circle element so that the flag works for both?